# What FRAGS argument does in RediSearch FT.SEARCH command?

Tags: redisearch

I looked through [RediSearch documentation](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Commands/#ftalter) and the syntax of `FT.SEARCH` below:

```
FT.SEARCH {index} {query} [NOCONTENT] [VERBATIM] [NOSTOPWORDS] [WITHSCORES] [WITHPAYLOADS] [WITHSORTKEYS]
  [FILTER {numeric_field} {min} {max}] ...
  [GEOFILTER {geo_field} {lon} {lat} {raius} m|km|mi|ft]
  [INKEYS {num} {key} ... ]
  [INFIELDS {num} {field} ... ]
  [RETURN {num} {field} ... ]
  [SUMMARIZE [FIELDS {num} {field} ... ] [FRAGS {num}] [LEN {fragsize}] [SEPARATOR {separator}]]
  [HIGHLIGHT [FIELDS {num} {field} ... ] [TAGS {open} {close}]]
  [SLOP {slop}] [INORDER]
  [LANGUAGE {language}]
  [EXPANDER {expander}]
  [SCORER {scorer}]
  [PAYLOAD {payload}]
  [SORTBY {field} [ASC|DESC]]
  [LIMIT offset num]
```

I cannot find anywhere description of `FRAGS`. What `FRAGS` argument does in RediSearch `FT.SEARCH` command? Is there any limit for `{num}` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a fragment is a substring of the search result which contains contextual information related to the search term; for example, when searching for "Redis", a fragment in a document might be

"found. Users liked **Redis** more than other..."

This is part of the [summarization](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Highlight.html) feature

Comment: Thanks, at the time of asking question the reference inside docs didn't work, so I was puzzled.